# Adding custom slugs: parent-page/username/child-page/

Tags: rewrite-rules, child-pages

I'm in a bit of a muddle understanding how I can change my `$_GET` variables into a 'slug'. I already have a setup of a `parent-page/child-page` using `wp_insert_post`. BUT! I want to add a variable in-between to create the setup of `parent-page/?username=bob/child-page`.

I was looking at [add_rewrite_rule](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule) to change my format from `index.php?page_id=PAGE_ID&username=bob` to `/users/bob/about/`.

I've tried this:

```
public static function add_rewrite(){
    $page=get_page_by_title('users');
    add_rewrite_rule('^users/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?','index.php?page_id='.$page->ID.'&username=$matches[1]','top');
}
//quickly to show how called.
add_action('init',array(__CLASS__,'add_rewrite');
```

This doesn't work but I was hoping to at least achieve `users/username/` so that I can figure out how to add my child page later.

Sorry if I'm confusing!!

**EDIT!!**

I managed to sort out my errors. This is what I've achieved so far:

```
public static function add_vars($public_query_vars){
    $public_query_vars[]='username';
    return$public_query_vars;
}
public static function addRewriteRule(){
    $page=get_page_by_title('users');
    //add_rewrite_rule('^leaf/([0-9]+)/?', 'index.php?page_id=$matches[1]','top');
    add_rewrite_rule('^users/([^/]+)/?$','index.php?page_id='.$page->ID.'&username=$matches[1]','top');
}
```

So now I can access `get_query_var('username');` But! I'm still unable to get my child page for the parent page, any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution!

I was trying to over complicate things. The best method I've come up with is:

```
    $users=get_page_by_title('users');
    $about=get_page_by_title('about');
    add_rewrite_rule('^users/([^/]*)$','index.php?page_id='.$users->ID.'&username=$matches[1]','top');
    add_rewrite_rule('^users/([^/]*)/about/?','index.php?page_id='.$about->ID.'&username=$matches[1]','top');
```

Haven't come up with errors yet, haven't tested yet!